# Laravel : Should I extend my User class to 'Authenticatable'?

Tags: angularjs, laravel-5

Im building an app with AngularJS and Laravel. I'm currently working on a login page. 
By default in Laravel, the 'out of the box' class User extends 'Authenticatable' but I would like to know if I can rather simply extend it to 'Model', because I actually want to rule my authentication access through AngularJS routing and not via Laravel. 
 I don't know if this makes sense.. and if this would even work (I dont wanna break the logic behind Laravel). Could anyone help me on that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Authenticatable refers to `Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User` which in turn includes some [Traits](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php) and implements some contracts, depending on whether you're going to use Laravel's Auth system it seems like you can omit extending this class without any problems.

Comment: Thanks for that ! Im gonna make some tests today :)